# Как реализовать смену полей

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы при нажатии менялись поля местами

Comment: Ну, видимо, просто менять местами значения полей. Покажите свой код и тогда сможете получить более предметный ответ.

Comment: Речь идёт за поменять поля местами или за перемещение данных в полях при сохранении логики обработки полей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var button = document.getElementById('switch');
var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var input1Val = input1.value;
  var input2Val = input2.value;
  
  input1.value = input2Val;
  input2.value = input1Val;
});
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" id="input1" class="field__input">
</div>
<button id="switch">o</button>
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" id="input2" class="field__input">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!